# FrameLayout background is inconsistent

Tags: android, layout, background

I have a Fragment where I have a FrameLayout inside a RelativeLayout that displays some data.
When I set its background by color , it's fine, it colors only the frame layout , and when I set a custom background I make - it paints the whole screen on top of the main layout. 
What can be the reason for it?

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/pixel_background"
    >

<FrameLayout 
       android:id="@+id/codeLayout"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:background="@drawable/cusotom_background"
       android:paddingTop="25dp"
       android:paddingBottom="25dp">   

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/passwordDisplayTextView"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#57C4BE"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize" />
</FrameLayout>
....
```

thanks.

Comment: Can you add your xml here?

Comment: "when I set a custom background I make" what do you mean?

Comment: I created a background in photoshop.. put it in Drawable and use it (trying to at least..)

Comment: ok, you created it in photoshop, what's next? post some images maybe?

Comment: reference it in android:background

Comment: Screenshots would really help us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have enough reputation for add comment.
My suggestion is why you set the height of your frame layout to wrap content instead of taking it as match parent.

Comment: because I don't want it to stretch all over the screen , that's the point. 
I want that background set just in certain part..

Comment: take a imageview & set that behind of all other views, it will be shown as background of your view & you can set it where ever you want